# How to throw NotFoundResourceException with code status code 404 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to throw a `NotFoundResourceException` in Laravel programmatically

```php
  use Symfony\Component\Translation\Exception\NotFoundResourceException;
  
  throw new NotFoundResourceException('The Item you could not be found', 404);
```

From the code editor I can see the hint that the second parameter is the code but this returns status 500 instead of 404
[image]

`throw new NotFoundResourceException('The Item you could not be found');` without the parameter also returns status 500

I can use `abort(404)` as suggested in [How to make Laravel 5 return 404 status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42614264/how-to-make-laravel-5-return-404-status-code) but is there a way to `throw` 404 error?

Comment: abort() means it throw and abort all the opration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you have imported wrong one `NotFoundResourceException` instead of `NotFoundHttpException`

`NotFoundResourceException`  extended from `Exception`

```
public function __construct($message = "", 
                            $code = 0,
                           Throwable $previous = null
                          )
```

So it wont throw http exception .

If you look at implementation of `NotFoundHttpException` which is extended from `HttpException` .Constructor has

```
     public function __construct(?string $message = '', 
                                  \Throwable $previous = null, 
                                   int $code = 0, 
                                   array $headers = []
                                 )
```

So it accept second argument as `$previous exception`

```
try {
        test();
    } catch(Error $e) {

        throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException("not found pagew",$e,404);
    }
```

Now if we catch error in   `App\Exceptions\Handler`

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
            dump($e->getMessage());
            dump($e->getCode());
            dd($e->getPrevious());

        }

        return parent::render($request, $e); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
```

it will print like below

> "not found pagew"
>
> 404
>
> Error {#353 ▼   #message: "Call to undefined function test()"   #code:
> 0   #file: "I:\xampp\htdocs\adbs\live\sra\routes\web.php"   #line: 28
> trace: {▶} }